# POST request body with filters in react native

Tags: react-native, http-post

I want to add filters in my request so that I only get my datas when the filter is true.
Unfortunatly, my code doesn't run and I don't know why

```
mySuperFunction() {
fetch('myhttps', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query: {
      bool: {
        filter: [{ term: { mySuperTerm: true } }],
      },
    },
    size: 1000,
  }),
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    if (json.found) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 4));
    } 
    else {
        console.log('error');}
   })
```

What I want to extract is all datas when my filter = true:

```
  "data": {
    "name": "eddy",
    "city": "london",
    "mySuperTerm": true,
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean when you refer filter?

Comment: look at my edit

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you get no error back at all? Nothing happening?

Wrap Accept in single quotes.

Comment: I got  "GET /onchange HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "okhttp/3.6.0"

Comment: Catch the error

.catch((err) => console.log(err));

Comment: Probably need to see the code running on the back end then?

Comment: When it runs, I only got  "GET /onchange HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "okhttp/3.6.0" . Nothing else :(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it seems to be a bug from react native
See [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22095)